# Dreamweaver switch between code and design view selects all internal CSS

Tags: dreamweaver

So I'm new to Dreamweaver.

When switching back and forth between 'code' and 'design' views, I'm usually taken back to the line of code I was originally editing.

However, when I have internal CSS in my file (like in the email newsletter I'm designing now), when I switch back to code view from design, it selects all my CSS and I find myself at the top of the file.

This is really frustrating because I end up searching for the line of CSS I was typing in.

Is there a good reason for this happening? I must be missing something.

---

Also, I'm looking for the shortcut to toggle code/split/design views. Dreamweaver tells me it's CTRL+' (apostrophe). But neither the control nor command button work with that shortcut on my 13" Macbook Pro.

---

Currently running Adobe CS5 on OSX 10.8.

Comment: To switch views for mac is CMD+`  (back tick not apostrophe)

Comment: Aw man, that isn't even a key on my macbook

Comment: Really, it's on my MacBook Pro, and according to the photo of the AIR  keyboard on this page: http://www.apple.com/macbookair/design.html it's on the upper left just below the ESC key (same place on my MBP).